# how to loop through data and assign values to state array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component and its state contains a filterItems[] blank array. I need to populate the values inside the filterItems array

So, I have a data coming from API which looks something like this:

```
0:
emp_code: "a001"
company_code: "company_a"
keys: ["id", "post" ] 
dtypes: ["str", "int"]

1:
emp_code: "b001"
company_code: "company_b"
keys: ["sal", "name" ] 
dtypes: ["int", "str"]

//so on for other companies and employees
```

So, like this I have a few employees. 
Now I have to loop through this api data and extract the information and store it  into another array called "filters" and pass it to a function.

My filter array should look something like this:

```
filters: [
        {
          key_name: "id",
          company_code: "company_a",
          input_type: "text",
          dtype: "str"
        },
        {
          key_name: "post",
          company_code: "company_a",
          input_type: "text",
          dtype: "int"
        },
//... keys for other company
]
```

essentially,
I need to do the following in react

```
for each emp_code
  for each company_code
     for each key:
         keys[i]== filters.key_name
         company_code== filters.company_code
//...so on
```

The catch here is that, each company has a set of keys so if the employee belongs to the same company then I dont need to add again to the filter array.
So, I basically need to check unique company_code and add the different types of keys a company has to the filters array.

Comment: why don't you add the data from api, instead of console log?

Comment: Is it the algorithm you are struggling with or where to do it in React so it makes sense? If you use a react from on 16.6, I think `getDerivedStateFromProps` might be an appropriate place to put your mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you want to filter your data like this:

Let's say you store your API data in a variable called `myArr`

Create a new variable called `updatedArr` that will map over `myArr`

```
const updatedArr = myArr.map((company, compIndex, compArr) => {
    return company.keys.map((key, keyIndex, keyArr) => {
        return {
            key_name: key,
            company_code: company.company_code,
            input_type: "text",
            dtype: company.dtypes[keyIndex]
        }
    })
}).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return [...acc, ...cur]
}, [])
```

Then parse updatedArr to get the uniqueValues only

```
let uniqueValues = [];
//parses out duplicates
updatedArr.forEach(function(item) {
  //i will be 0 or more if there already is an item in our array, which means the current item we are iterating over is a duplicate
  var i = uniqueValues.findIndex(
    x => x.dtype == item.dtype && x.company_code == item.company_code
  );
  if (i <= -1) {
    //if item is not yet inside uniqueValues, add it to uniueValues
    uniqueValues.push(item);
  }
});
```

Then update your componentState with the uniqueValues

```
this.setState({
   filters: uniqueValues
})
```

Also created a sandbox to show you this working in-action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-companies-ibs7g

Comment: This works correct, can you also show how to check the uniqueness of the company. So basically if the company already exists I dont want it to add the company again.

Comment: @user8306074 Ohhhhh. So you only want to have the company added once, what do you do with the different keys and data-types then? Dont they need their own objects? The desired output you showed us has multiple of the same company_code, so its rather unclear what you want to make :/

Comment: So basically, I want to apply a filter on each company_code based on keys. So keys are the columns in my dataset and they are key identifiers of a company. So I want to apply any filtering based on the company_code and retrieve emp_code of those filters. Your code is working good. But it generates an output for each row. So If I have two employees of the same company then it will create two identical objects in the filters array. Thus, I want the company_code to be unqiue

Comment: So, If my array reads the same company_code again, reject it, and move to the next row. I guess we need an if condition to check this after the first map loop

Comment: Hmmm that's a possible solution. Right now we generate an object for each unique key in the company, which I think makes sense for how you want to consume this data. I think we actually need to configure your Table code so that it knows how to properly filter this data. That might be a separate question altogether though.

Comment: Oh, isn't it possible to add a if condition to check if the company_code exists then dont do anything, if it doesnt then add it to the continue. I'm trying to do that but it is difficult to check at the runtime which values are already added and which are not

Comment: Hmmm we could, but then we wouldnt be able to get all the necessary keys yknow? We would end up generating only a single object for each company and only have one of the keys from the keys array. For instance, if we create map over company_a's keys, you're saying you only want to return a single instance of company_a, that means we would only be able to get key "id", we wont make an object for "post" since that will be a duplicate of company_a. If we do that, we wont be getting all the keys, I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Ohh I get what you mean, but if I place it above the second map function,so it will loop over all the keys in company_a and then move onto next company

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193812/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-user8306074).

Comment: @user8306074 updated the answer and sandbox with how to make the values unique. Lemme know if that works. :)

Comment: Thank you so much.! It is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a array.

```
    let filters = [];

    data.forEach(item => {
        item.keys.forEach(key => {
            item.dtypes.forEach(dtype => {
                const filter = {
                    key_name: key,
                    company_code: item.company_code,
                    input_type: "text",
                    dtype: dtype
                };
                filters.push(filter)
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: So this will loop over each key and generate two outputs for different dtypes but in my state: key id has a dtype str and post has a dtype as int. So I need to loop over keys and dtypes at the same time

Comment: Yes. it is done in the above snippet. First Loop all the items on the outerLoop. Then loop all the keys, and loop all the dtypes in the innerLoop and create the new object and push it to the filters. Try this snippet and let me know your thoughts